# $100! $ in terms of $2^m Z$

Tags: factorial, factoring

**Question**

I have encountered an question. 
 If $$ 100! = 2^m Z $$
Where $Z\notin2\mathbb Z$ is an integer, find $m$ where $m \in \mathbb{ Z^+} $

**My Attempt**
As 
$$100! = 2^{50} 50!$$ $[ 1×3×5×6. . . × 99]$
$$50! = 2^{25} 25!$$ $[1×3×5. . . ×25]$

Similarly the successive terms can be written.

$ 100! =  2^{50} {2^{25}}$ (ODD term)

$100! = 2^{75} 24!$

So
$$100! = 2^{97}$$
So $m = 97$
Is my approch correct ? Or it will need improvement.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

$^*:\mathbb{ Z}^+$

Comment: $(2n)!\ne2^n\cdot n!$.

Comment: $m\in\mathbb{I}$ ? are you sure?

Comment: @LuisFelipe Using $\Bbb I$ instead of $\Bbb Z$ for the integers is presumably a rarer convention based on English games instead of German ones.

Comment: @J.G.yeah, I throught it was a mistake because in rarely notation $\mathbb{I}$ means irrational numbers or even pure imaginary numbers.

Comment: So for integer i have to use $\mathBbb Z $. Ok

Comment: @VedantChourey remember to mark any answer as "accepted answer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to find the exponent of a prime number $p$ in $N!$, you have to look how many times it appears (it will appear every $p$ numbers, and every $p^2$ numbers it will appear twice, and every $p^3$ numbers it will appear three times, etc).

So you are looking for the number  : 
$$\Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{100}{2} \Bigr\rfloor+\Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{100}{2^2} \Bigr\rfloor+\Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{100}{2^3}\Bigr\rfloor+\cdots$$

which also is [Legendre's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)

Comment: That's Legendre's formula.

Comment: I got that, thankyou very much.

Comment: @VedantChourey if your questions has been solved, don't forget to mark an answer as "correct answer" for helping other users with your same question to find an answer ;)

Comment: How to do this operation? Actually i'm operating the site through an android application, so i don't know how to perform the above mentioned action. Please give direction

Comment: just as $ \lfloor 50 \rfloor + \lfloor 25 \rfloor + \lfloor 12.5 \rfloor + \lfloor 6.25\rfloor + .... $. eventually the other terms will be 0

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to do this:

$$\lfloor\dfrac{100}{2}\rfloor + \lfloor\dfrac{100}{2^2}\rfloor + \lfloor\dfrac{100}{2^3}\rfloor +...$$
$$=50+25+12+6+3+1$$
$$=97$$

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct!! But lets do some smart work (instead of hard). Use Legendre's formula which states that maximum power of prime $p$, that divides $n!$ is $$\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p}\rfloor + \lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^2}\rfloor + \lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^3}\rfloor +...$$which obviously converges for sufficiently large value of $p^i$.

Comment: And the $i$ is ?

Comment: I just meant that for sufficiently large $i$, all terms after $\lfloor\frac{n}{p^i}\rfloor$ becomes $0$.

Comment: Ok got that. Thankyou